# ¿Cómo me es posible personalizar mi perfil en SO usando spoilers?

Tags: soporte, perfil

El otro día me he encontrado con este [perfil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/squint) en SOen con efecto sobre el `blockquote`.

Y por lo visto ha metido la clase `spoiler` en el `blockquote`.

¿Es un hack o un bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es simple de hacer, solo debes usar `>!` en tu perfil (sí funciona, puedes ver mi perfil por ejemplo, en la parte inferior). Es parte del soporte adicional de markdown que se ofrece en el sitio.

La referencia oficial está

> [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers)

Detalle:

> Para ocultar cierta parte de un texto y que solo sea visible cuando un usuario mueve el mouse sobre este, utiliza la sintaxis de la cita en bloque con un signo de exclamación adicional:
>
> ```
> Al final del quinto episodio se revela que
> >! él es en realidad su padre.
> ```

Comment: Y mira que estaba buscando y probando... Gracias por la aclaración!

Comment: Wow! Como mola esto. Muchas gracias por la info :)

Comment: Spoiler alert: >! @Luiggi Mendoza la tiene re clara!